# String Tokenizer missing 2 values off array

Tags: java, android, stringtokenizer

I am taking creating a `StringTokenizer` like so and populating an `ArrayList` using the tokens:

```
LogUtils.log("saved emails: " + savedString);
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(savedString, ",");
mListEmailAddresses = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < st.countTokens(); i++) {

     String strEmail = st.nextToken().toString();
     mListEmailAddresses.add(strEmail);

}

LogUtils.log("mListEmailAddresses: emails: " + mListEmailAddresses.toString());

11-20 09:56:59.518: I/test(6794): saved emails: hdhdjdjdjd,rrfed,ggggt,tfcg,
11-20 09:56:59.518: I/test(6794): mListEmailAddresses: emails: [hdhdjdjdjd, rrfed]
```

As you can see `mListEmailAddresses` is missing 2 values off the end of the array. What should I do to fix this. From my eyes the code looks correct but maybe I am misunderstanding something.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to use while loop i think. and use the function hasMoreTokens() for checking if there is more tokenz.

Comment: st.countTokens() returns the count of tokens remaining.  Not the total count of tokens

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html  .  See this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following while loop

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(savedString, ",");
mListEmailAddresses = new ArrayList<String>();
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {

     String strEmail = st.nextToken();
     mListEmailAddresses.add(strEmail);
}
```

Note, you don't need to call `toString`, `nextToken` will return the string.

Alternatively, you could use the `split` method

```
String[] tokens = savedString.split(",");
mListEmailAddresses = new ArrayList<String>();
mListEmailAddresses.addAll(Arrays.asList(tokens));
```

Note, the API docs for `StringTokenizer` state:

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility
>   reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended
>   that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String
>   or the java.util.regex package instead.

Answer (score 1):

using `hasMoreTokens` is the solution

```
 while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
         String strEmail = st.nextToken().toString();
         mListEmailAddresses.add(strEmail);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Ill remember this for future :). I knew it was something to do with my function calling.

Answer (score 0):

`st.countTokens()` method calculates the number of times that this `tokenizer's nextToken()` method can be called before it generates an exception. The current position is not advanced.

To get all elements in `ArrayList` you should use following code

```
while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String strEmail =  st.nextToken().toString();
    mListEmailAddresses.add(strEmail);
}
```